# Andorid - how to pick files from another application install in mobile

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api, dropbox

I have a question, that how user can pick file from another application installed on device like Dropbox, google drive, outbox etc.?
I want to know is it possible or not. If yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is possible, and the process for each of this is different, first and foremost you will need to study up on OAuth 1 and Oauth 2 protocols, then you can start acting as proxy for the user and choose files from his dropbox google drive account.

Comment: So acc. to you there are different OAuth 1 and Oauth protocols for installed application in mobile?

Comment: No the protocols are same, but the steps to get the application id, application secret keys are different, and each of these have their own variation of the protocol too.

Comment: Can you suggested me any sample code or any help for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, and the process for each of this is different, first and foremost you will need to study up on OAuth 1 and Oauth 2 protocols, then you can start acting as proxy for the user and choose files from his dropbox google drive account

For google drive

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/

For Dropbox

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android